# MariaDB - Roll Back an entire transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, mariadb, rollback

With Most DBMSs, when a statement inside transaction fails, the whole transaction rolls back. For example:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    code INT CHECK(code>0),
    data VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO test(code,data) VALUES(23,'apple');

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO test(code,data) VALUES(45,'banana');
INSERT INTO test(code,data) VALUES(-3,'banjo');     --  error

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM test;
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/tpTNoMGo

The statement before the transaction should succeed. The transaction contains a failed insert, so the transaction should be rolled back. Isn’t that the whole point of a transaction?

When I `SELECT * FROM TEST`, I get the `banana` row which was added inside the transaction.

It seems that MySQL / MariaDB only rolls back the failed statement, which is pretty pointless as it’s failed anyway.

What is required to have the whole transaction rolled back?

Comment: most DBMSs?  It doesn't look like that to me. from a cursory googling: Oracle behaves like mysql; postgres enters a special mode where no further statements are allowed until you explicitly rollback or go to a savepoint; SQL Server defaults to working like mysql but has a xact_abort setting to automatically roll back the entire transaction.  Curious to know which DBMSs you are referring to.

Comment: @ysth Hmm. I might need to amend that. PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL roll back the whole transaction. SQLite doesn’t, and I still haven’t worked out what’s happening with Oracle.

Comment: that's not what I saw from the postgres/MS doc

Comment: @ysth See fiddles at https://dbfiddle.uk/DpBR-woZ and https://dbfiddle.uk/8-V4FPhX . I could be wrong, however, as I’m not sure how the different sections in the code are being treated.

Answer (score 1):

What's required to rollback the entire transaction is that you write code to execute `ROLLBACK` (or equivalent API call).

The reason a single failed statement doesn't roll back the whole transaction is to give you an opportunity to retry the statement, or do some alternative change, or whatever you feel is appropriate for your application.